# get the least Frequent item from array of objects

Tags: php

I'm trying to output `[device_id]` of the least frequent `[device_ip_isp]` from this array.
Also, If the array only has two SharedDevice Object available, and having different `[device_ip_isp]`, it should output the 2nd SharedDevice Object's  `[device_id]`

```
array (
      0 => 
      SharedDevice::__set_state(array(
         'device_no' => 1,
         'device_id' => '82',
         'device_ip_isp' => 'Verizon Fios',
      )),
      1 => 
      SharedDevice::__set_state(array(
         'device_no' => 2,
         'device_id' => '201',
         'device_ip_isp' => 'Spectrum',
      )),
      2 => 
      SharedDevice::__set_state(array(
         'device_no' => 3,
         'device_id' => '312',
         'device_ip_isp' => 'Verizon Fios',
      )),
      3 => 
      SharedDevice::__set_state(array(
         'device_no' => 4,
         'device_id' => '9715',
         'device_ip_isp' => 'Verizon Fios',
      )),
      4 => 
      SharedDevice::__set_state(array(
         'device_no' => 5,
         'device_id' => '11190',
         'device_ip_isp' => 'Verizon Fios',
      )),
    )
```

The output should be `201` because "`Spectrum`" is the least frequent.

I tried the following and had issues:
I'm not sure how I can sort the object variables before comparing to find the least frequent.

```
/*
 $user->getUser_devices() will output the array shown above.
*/

leastFrequent($user->getUser_devices(), 5);

function leastFrequent($arr, $n){


    // find the min frequency
    // using linear traversal
    $min_count = $n + 1;
    $res = -1;
    $curr_count = 1;
    for ($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i]['device_ip_isp'] == $arr[$i - 1]['device_ip_isp']) {
            $curr_count++;
        } else {
            if ($curr_count < $min_count) {
                $min_count = $curr_count;
                $res = $arr[$i - 1]['device_id'];
            }
            $curr_count = 1;
        }
    }

    // If last element is
    // least frequent
    if ($curr_count < $min_count) {
        
        $min_count = $curr_count;
        $res = $arr[$n - 1]['device_id'];
    }

    return $arr[$n]$res['device_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, below is the explanation of the snippet inside out.

- [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get all the `device_ip_isp` values in a single array.
- [`array_count_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get the frequency of each value.
- [`array_reverse`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to reverse the count frequency array since you need the latest share device ID incase of count collision for a minimum count value.
- [`min`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min) to get the lowest value among all the frequency counts.
- [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the key of the first frequency min element.
- In the end, we reverse the input array to immediate return the device IP the moment we find the key from the above step matching the current `device_ip_isp`.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getLeastFrequentElement($arr){
  $freqs = array_reverse(array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'device_ip_isp')));
  $deviceIPISP = array_search(min($freqs), $freqs);
  foreach(array_reverse($arr) as $sharedDevice){
    if($sharedDevice->device_ip_isp === $deviceIPISP){
      return $sharedDevice->device_id;
    }
  }

  throw new Exception("No shared object found!");
}


echo getLeastFrequentElement($arr);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3ys59m2ce)